# Flex HTTPService security error using Safari

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, safari, httpservice

I'm using the HTTPService object in actionscript to send some data to a php file on another server which then inserts the data to a database.  I set up the crossdomain.xml file in the root of the directory that contains the php file to get around any security issues.

Everything works fine on Firfox 3.5 (on mac and pc) and on IE 7 & 8.  When testing on Safari 4 I get an error which would be expected when a crossdomain.xml doesn't exist.

> [RPC Fault faultString="Security error
>   accessing url"
>   faultCode="Channel.Security.Error"
>   faultDetail="Destination:
>   DefaultHTTP"]     at
>   mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::faultHandler()
>     at mx.rpc::Responder/fault()    at
>   mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/fault()  at
>   DirectHTTPMessageResponder/securityErrorHandler()
>     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>     at
>   flash.net::URLLoader/redirectEvent()

Any ideas on how to get this to work on Safari?  It's seems as if Safari isn't accessing the crossdomain.xml file.

Comment: This randomly started working a day after I ran into the problem...  I turned on the inspector element in safari to view the GETs and POSTs and it suddenly worked.  Your guesses are as good as mine.